# Whenever i run this statement,the displayed link only goes to the testimonials.php and even if the id !=4

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, hyperlink

this block is for fetching the database table rows to display its content, the product count will count the if the table contains any data

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products1 ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 10");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

     echo  '<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">';
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td width="17%" valign="top"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="../inventory_images/'.$row['id'].'.png" alt="'.$row['name'].'" width="90" height="110" border="1"/></td>';
     echo '<td width="83%" valign="top">'.$row['name'].'<br/>P'.$row['price'].'<br />';
```

This one is for the links, If the product being diplayed had an id of 4 it should go to testimonials.php and if it contains an id of 5, it should go to the register.php and if it contains an id of 6, it should go to a.php and so on

```
     if ($id=4){
     echo '<a href="testimonials.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     elseif ($id=5){
     echo '<a href="register.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     elseif ($id=6){
     echo '<a href="a.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     elseif ($id=7){
     echo '<a href="b.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     elseif ($id=8){
     echo '<a href="c.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     elseif ($id=9){
     echo '<a href="d.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     elseif ($id=10){
     echo '<a href="e.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     elseif ($id=11){
     echo '<a href="f.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     elseif ($id=12){
     echo '<a href="g.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     elseif ($id=13){
     echo '<a href="h.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     elseif ($id=14){
     echo '<a href="i.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';}

     echo '</tr>';
     echo '</table>';

      }
```

If it had 0 data the product count should say "we have no product listed on the store yet"

```
   }else
      {
        echo "We have no product listed in our store yet";
      }
      mysql_close(); 

 ?>
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison

Comment: You're assigning in all your conditionals, instead of comparing. Search and replace will fix that in a jiffy. In like, 0.125 seconds *flat*.

Comment: You probably want `echo  '<table....` before the loop and only the `<tr>` and `<td>` part inside the loop.  As it stands, each iteration of the loop will make a new table (once you fix the `=` vs `==` thing).

Comment: thank you, what happened is when i started replacing it by == the links disappeared

Comment: The obvious question is why you even want a chain of ifs like `if($id=6){ echo '<a href="a.php?` rather than just echo something like `echo "<a href='product.php?id={$id}'>"`...with no need for any ifs.

Comment: Or 0.120 seconds *round* @Fred-ii- But I digress.

Comment: and why the `</td>`'s at the end of each `href`; no idea. Probably why your links are disappearing.

Comment: @JayBlanchard [I stand corrected...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) *Afternoon Sam!*

Comment: Oh, *by the way*.... how/where is the notorious `$id` variable being assigned?

Comment: the id is comming from the products table item

Comment: Because i am displaying products with an image an if for example the image being displayed is hat which had an id of 7 it should go to the b.php which contains all the description of that certain product if they want to purchase it

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty painful. Repeated conditions like that, which differ only minutely are better done with a lookup table:

```
$map = array(
   4 => 'testimonials',
   5 => 'register',
   6 => 'a'
   etc..
)

if (isset($map[$id])) {
    echo '<a href="' . $map$[$id] . '.php?">View Product Details</a></td>';
}
```

And like mentioned in all the comments, you're doing ASSIGNMENTS in your `if()` tests:

```
if ($id = 4) {
        ^---
```

In PHP, the result of assignment is the value being assigned, so `$id` gets assigned the value `4`, and then evaluation continues on as if the statement had been

```
if (4) {
```

Since `4` is a non-false value, this will ALWAYS evaluate to `true` and the rest of the `else` causes will be ignored.

Comment: thank you, is that possible inside while loop? be cause i tried placing it inside but it shows an error